# Paypal ExpressCheckout - How to show some note that tells Merchant which site this sale came from?

Tags: php, paypal

The merchant/seller paypal has so many transactions coming in, and i would like to place a note/message or some code in transactions that tells the seller that from which website this sale is coming from.

Is this possible?

Please advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass a field called `custom` which can contain any information you wish:

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html

search for `CUSTOM`

I would image your input being passed to paypal would look something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>">
```

Comment: This example is for Payments Standard.  With Express Checkout you can still use this, but it's just a matter of adding the CUSTOM parameter to your API request as oppose to using hidden fields in a basic HTML form.